# Compiler error dispatcher-servlet.xml spring mvc + hibernate

Tags: java, spring

Im have an error in my dispatcher-servlet.xml and i need more information to try solve this problem. I have been looking in google about this problem, and i found that maybe its an error in dependencies or my schema. But both, are all right. My schema in the dispatcher-servlet.xml its without versions on the xsd's, i follow this rule because its a good practice. This is my compiler error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [property] Offending resource: file [C:/Users/CarlosGil/Desktop/
     Spring/SpringMVCHelloWorld/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
    - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [property].
```

It fails here:

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<!-ERROR HERE-->        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

This is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.controller" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <!-- <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->


    <beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/EMPLEADOS" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="admin" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="admin" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.datadyne.spring.model.Empleado</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="empDAO" class="com.datadyne.spring.dao.EmpleadoDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="empleadoService"
        class="com.datadyne.spring.service.EmpleadoServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="empDAO" ref="empDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.datadyne.spring" />


    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>



</beans:beans>
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.srccodes.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVCHelloWorld</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMVCHelloWorld Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVCHelloWorld</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Anyone with good knowledge in spring, can give an advice how can i solve it?

This is my web.xml too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: show me your web.xml

Comment: Ok Byenon0gam, i have refreshed the content of my question

Comment: No one can help me?? :/

Answer (score 1):

edit some code.

(your web.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

I think to wrong your definition file. 
already build your dispatcher. you use context-param in root-servlet.xml. don`t use same dispatcher file. your search document spring definition settings. you can do it. :)

Comment: Sorry for answer so late, i think that my error was on the path of the properties. <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>   Now is working fine, and i can deploy mi spring mvc project. Thank you for your efforts Byeon0gam..